# Nonequivalent matrices change of base

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the fact that
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
are not equivalent matrices over the integers where equivalent means that I can't get from one to the other via a change of base.  I don't see why this is true.
Furthermore,  I'm told that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
*are* equivalent.  Could someone help me find a change of base to show these are equivalent?